# How can I change the default timeout using KIF?

Tags: ios, kif

I am using KIF for developing tests, but sometimes because I am getting data from a service that takes more than 10 seconds a tests fails, so I would like to know how to change the default timeout.

Is there other solution for this issue I was trying:

```
[tester waitForAbsenceOfViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Configuración"];
```

However, it seems this function is not working properly so I have decided to increase the timeout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about something like:

```
[[tester usingTimeout:60]  waitForAbsenceOfViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Configuración"];
```

[See also this blog post.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61419/ios-ui-testing-with-kif)  On a side note, you might want to look into mock or dummy services to lessen the time taken to test and decrease the load on your services.